# Creating a back button to a previous activity (CONCEPT ONLY)

Tags: android, android-studio

Before I say anything else, I am not asking how to make this work for my program, I want to figure it out myself. I have already seen one billion snippets of codes and answers. But I think I am not understanding the concept behind it and would like to verify if my understanding is correct.

Creating a back button and making it work:
1) Find and edit the xml for the action bar so show a back button.
2) Use the buttons id to create OnClickListener.
3) In OnClick, use intent to previous activity.

Is it not this simple? What are the proper steps conceptually for make this work?

Answer (score 1):

That might work, but it wouldn't be the norm.
Depending on how you launch an `Activity`, simply calling `finish()` on an `Activity` will take you back to the previous one.

easier to

1) use `AppCompatActivity`

2) enable homeAsUp (back button)

`ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)`

Comment: By "use AppCompatActivity" you mean inherit the class correct? And the norm for editing the action bar is to use java only, no xml? Is there literature on this?

Comment: yup, plenty of detail here - https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html

Comment: The method you explained restarts the parent activity. What if you want it to load the activity's last state before you switched activity?

Comment: the previous activity should only restart if it was destroyed by the OS or by calling finish() when launching the new one.

Answer (score 1):

Android activities are stored in the activity **stack**.

So simply by calling the **finish()** method if you started the activity with **startActivity()**

> this.finish()

or if you opened the new activity from another activity with **startActivityForResult()** 
call the **finishActivity()** method from your code on the click of the button

> this.finishActivity()

And it'll take you back to the previous activity.

Answer (score 0):

Well..... I don't know this answer would be helpful but, you said

> 3) In OnClick, use intent to previous activity.

However, how about thinking this situation?

If there is fragment and you press 'back button' in there, you should go **before fragment** not before activity. :)

You said you want to figure it out yourself so, I won't say more(about codes) as you wanted. Good Luck!

Comment: I'm a self taught "coder" and am not currently familiar with the term "fragment" obviously I will now look into it, but is this concept a requirement for my understanding of action bar manipulation?

Comment: Ah...... I think I misunderstand what you asked. Don't you mean you want to make **Re-creative Back Button**? Just like, Red-Back button, Blue-back button, rectangular one or something else which do same "back button" function??

Comment: Well.. If you study concept of back button, you should study `Flag`, `Activity Life Cycle`(Of course, `Fragment Life Cycle` too) Life cycle makes huge bug that you have to fix :)